# Problemas para mostrar enlaces del mapa actual

Tags: html, map

Tengo dos mapas hechos en una animación y ambos tienen enlaces dentro de elementos Map de html, tengo dos mapas porque uno es para la versión web y el otro se muestra en la verisón móvil (responsive), los enlaces de ambos funcionan bien si los coloco solos cada uno en el html pero cuando coloco ambos códigos, como se requiere, solo tienen los enlaces el mapa de la web y el responsive no. Yo lo que hago es ocultar el div para mostrar el que corresponda según la configuración de la pantalla, lo oculto con `display:none;` en el css. Probe colocanco las cordenadas de los enlaces tomando en cuenta la ubicación de ambos mapas (uno encima de otro) y no funcionó tampoco.

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center map map_img_large">
      <p>
        <div class="arrow" style="display:none;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/app/arrow.gif')}}" alt="">
        </div>
          <img name="usaMap" src="{{ asset('img/app/map.gif')}}" usemap="#m_usaMap" border="0" width="90%">
      </p>
      
      <map name="m_usaMap">
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="493,430, 19" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="516,299, 19" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="614,283, 19" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="655,248, 19"
        /></a>
      </map>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center map map_img_small">
      <p>
        <div class="arrow" style="display:none;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('img/app/arrow.gif')}}" alt="">
        </div>
          <img name="usaMap" src="{{ asset('img/app/responsive_map.gif')}}" usemap="#m_usaMap" border="0" width="90%">
      </p>

      <map name="m_usaMap">
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="234,239, 13" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="247,162, 13" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="325,133, 13" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.mienlace.com"><area shape="circle" coords="303,152, 13"
        /></a>
      </map>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes en el mismo documento dos elementos `MAP` con el mismo valor para el atributo `name`, lo cual es incorrecto. Necesitarías dar a cada `MAP` un `name` único, y modificar el valor del atributo `usemap` de los elementos `IMG` correspondientes.

Comment: gracias, lo había resulto así!